# Upgrading to SVN working copy 1.7 is taking forever

Tags: xcode, svn

How long should it take to upgrade to SVN working copy 1.7? When I upgraded to XCODE 1.5, I was prompted to upgrade to SVN 1.7. I selected Yes and it has been around 5 hours so far, the progress bar reached a certain spot and hasn't moved since.

[image: Screenshot for error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time depends on the size of your working copy, however it should not take so long. Try [`svn upgrade`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html) from command-line.